# Can Eddystone on Estimote beacons be configured using Proximity Beacon API provided by Google in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, estimote, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

I want to create an android app which supports configuring multiple Beacon manufacturers, apart from estimote. So, I am trying to come up with a generic solution to register a beacon.

I found that it can be done using Proximity Beacon API provided by Google.But when I try to use it, it is not able to connect to Estimote beacons.

I wanted to know, whether this approach is feasible or is there any approach to do it independently of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Most beacon manufacturers use only a proprietary configuration protocol to configure their beacons over Bluetooth.  This means you typically need to use a different configuration protocol for each manufacturer.   Some of these protocols are published and provide a SDK.  Others are not, and require reverse engineering.

Google attempted to create a standard configuration protocol in 2016, but adoption has been spotty at best.  Some manufacturers support it on some beacon models, and others not at all.  On any beacon firmware versions dating before mid-2016, support for Google's configuration protocol is almost certainly missing.

Bottom line: universal configuration is simply not possible as of late 2017.